# Trouble with getting handle of edit field in active window on c#

Tags: c#, winapi

i need to get handle of edit field in active window. This is standard windows open file window. [this is my window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QJ1n.jpg)

But, as you can see on image, this edit field have no title. So, i cannot use

```
FindWindowEx()
```

. How can i get handle in such case?

Comment: It seems the Dialog window has a name.

Comment: Edit element have no name.

Comment: You can dig through the Dialog.Controls until you find the first/second ComboBox

Comment: @noone Whether you have tried to use `UI automation`? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to interact with dialogs you did not create yourself the best solution is MSAA/UI Automation.

See [.Net and UI Automation overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview).

That being said, trying to interact with the open dialog in Chrome is probably not something you should be doing...